# CIBlockElement::GetList

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Подскажите, как правильно отфильтровать

```
    $arFilterSchet = array("IBLOCK_ID" => "88", "PROPERTY_398_VALUE" => $_GET['id']);
$resScheta =  CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilterSchet, false, array(), $arSelectScheta);

$obSchet = $resScheta->GetNextElement();

$data = $obSchet->GetFields();


    $arRes[] = [
        "id" => $data["ID"],
        "name" => $data["PROPERTY_398_VALUE"],
        ];
```

$data["PROPERTY_398_VALUE"] возвращает всегда только первое значение поля, не зависимо куда записали, то есть, есть 4 поля с id 145, 146, 147, 148

Мне выводит только 145,

Comment: Ну так смотрите что у вас в `$_GET['id']` попадает и откуда.

Answer (score 1):

Не используйте GetNextElement этот метод устарел.

вы достаете только один елемент измените свой код на:

```
$arFilterSchet = array("IBLOCK_ID" => "88", "PROPERTY_398_VALUE" => $_GET['id']);
$resScheta =  CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilterSchet, false, array(), $arSelectScheta);
while($data = $resScheta->GetNext()){
    $arRes[] = [
        "id" => $data["ID"],
        "name" => $data["PROPERTY_398_VALUE"],
    ];
}
```

Comment: CIBlockElement::GetList тоже можно назвать устаревшим, после выхода d7

Answer (score 1):

Вы делаете запрос данных `CIBlockElement::GetList`, а далее из полученных данных только один раз получаете запись `$resScheta->GetNextElement()`. Вот и выходит, что у вас только один элемент выводится.

Оберните в цикл запрос записей из полученных данных.

```php
while($r = $resScheta->GetNextElement()) {
    ...
}
```

Ну и как правильно сказал '@Сергей Савченко' - эти методы устарели, посмотрите в сторону bitrix d7. Но в принципе, старые методы не запрещается использовать... "пока" не запрещается.

Comment: на самом деле я просто выводил не ту переменную :D, в целом код выше правильный